# Subsetting rows while searching for 4 specific values in multiple columns

Tags: r, subset, large-data

I'm working with a large datatable (~1'000'000 x 700) and I want to subset the rows according to 4 specific values across multiple columns.

As I'm a beginner R-User I need help to achieve this.

The data.table looks as following:

[fictional DT in Excel, bold Values/Variables are the relevant one]
[image]

**What I'm looking for is a "fast" code that subsets every row that contains the values "X21" or "X22" or "X230" or "X231" (but not any ohter Xyza-Value) in any column starting with a "_7_2_Y" and ending with a zero (0) (50 variables which meets those criterias).**
The subseted rows should still contain every variable (but I think thats how it should be).

The subseted data should finally contain only relevant rows (and be small enough for further data maipulation).

I tried several things I read here, but without success (or without understanding how it works).

Subseting manualy using:

```
SubX <- subset(fulldata, 
            _7_2_Y10== X21 | _7_2_Y10== X22| _7_2_Y10== X230 | _7_2_Y10== X231|
            _7_2_Y20== X21 | _7_2_Y20== X22| _7_2_Y20== X230 | _7_2_Y20== X231|
            _7_2_Y30== X21 | _7_2_Y30== X22| _7_2_Y30== X230 | _7_2_Y30== X231|
            )
```

would be a pain.

I was told to use data.table (for fast subsetting/filtering) but it seems to have limitation to subset rows over multiple columns. Intermediate Steps might be needed but i really cant figure out how.

(I can't figure out how to use grep() as there is a value "X27" which I am not looking for.)

I hope my example is helpfull enough.
Thank you in advance,
L.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Gatitos Hermanos! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score -1):

We could use `filter` with `%in%` and `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
fulldata %>%
    filter(if_any(c(`_7_2_Y10`, `_7_2_Y20`, `_7_2_Y30`), ~ .x %in%
       c("X21", "X22", "X230", "X231")))
```